# Integration of $\frac{1}{x\ln(x)}$ by parts

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I tried to solve $\int \frac{dx}{x\ln(x)}$ by parts. I have done it as usual:
$$\int \frac{dx}{x\ln(x)}=\begin{bmatrix}
f(x)=\frac{1}{\ln x} & g'(x)=\frac{1}{x}\\ 
f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x\ln^2x} & g(x)=\ln x
\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{\ln x} \ln x - \int \left(-\frac{1}{x\ln^2x}\ln x\right)dx=$$ 
$$
=1+\int \left(\frac{dx}{x\ln x}\right)
$$ 
So, taking most left and right part we get:
$$
\int \frac{dx}{x\ln(x)}=1+\int \left(\frac{dx}{x\ln x}\right)
$$
By subtracting integral from both sides, we get:
$$
0=1
$$
I know that $\int \frac{dx}{x\ln(x)}=\ln(\ln x)+C$. However, I often use integration by parts and I wonder what is wrong here, and what should I do to avoid it (here it's plainly wrong, but what if the mistake was more subtle?). I guess may be something connected with constants, but I used to add them at the very end(wrongly?).

Comment: Consider the change of variable $u=\ln(x)$. Then, $du=\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}dx$. In this way, your integral is so easy, because by the change of variable we obtain $\displaystyle\int \displaystyle\frac{u}{du}$

Comment: Integral always involves constants.

Comment: Try to repeat the calculation with a *definite* integral, say from $1$ to $b$, and watch the “paradox” go up in smoke.

Answer (score 7):

When you subtract $\int \frac{dx}{x \log x}$ from $\int \frac{dx}{x \log x}$, remember that the two indefinite integrals could have different constants of integration, so all you know is that the difference is *some constant*.

In this case, what we learn from the integration by parts is just that "$1$ is a constant", which is not particularly enlightening.

Substituting $u=\log x$ as Carlos Jiménez suggests, ought to make more progress for this integral.

Comment: Thank you. I know I can solve this integral by substitution. My question is rather how to avoid such mistakes, when solving some more difficult integrals. Is it only some "rare phenomenon" or should I add a constant $C$ somewhere "in the middle" when integrating by parts?

Comment: @user351437: Usually it's not a problem -- for example, if you're subtracting $\frac13 \int f(x)dx$ from $\int f(x)dx$ to get $\frac23 \int f(x)dx$, the difference in constants is subsumed into the remaining integral. It's only when the integral vanishes completely that you need to represent the constant explicitly -- and then, like here, you're usually not getting anywhere _anyway_.

Answer (score 7):

What you did is correct, although inconclusive. The equalityy$$\int\frac{dx}{\ln x}=1+\int\frac{dx}{\ln x}$$simply means that there are primitives $f$ and $g$ of $\frac1{\ln x}$ such that $f=1+g$, a trivial assertion.

In order to compute the primitive, do$$\int\frac{dx}{x\ln x}=\int\frac{\ln'x}{\ln x}\,dx=\ln(\ln x)).$$

Answer (score 4):

A simpler example of this "paradox":
$$\int \frac1x \, dx = \int 1 \frac1x \, dx = x \frac1x - \int x \left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \, dx = 1 + \int \frac1x \, dx$$

Comment: Can you please clarify why do we have this problem with definite integrals as well? If we set to limits of the integration as a and b. We get b - a = 0

Comment: We do *not* have this problem with definite integrals:
$$
\int_a^b \frac1x dx = [1]_a^b + \int_a^b \frac1x dx = 0 + \int_a^b \frac1x dx.
$$
Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: Oh, thanks!! I made a mistake in my calculation

Answer (score 1):

This famous paradox has the simple resolution that, because the indefinite integrals are determined only up to a constant, you can explicitly verify things are OK if you instead use definite integrals. Note also that you can set up this paradox as your party trick with any choice satisfying $uv=c$, so that the original integrand is the derivative of $c\ln v$.